# Why do I have memory limit exceeded ? C#

Tags: c#, memory, limit, fibonacci

**The task is:**

1. The Tribonacci sequence is a sequence in which every next element is made by the sum of the previous three elements from the sequence.
2. Write a computer program that finds the Nth element of the Tribonacci sequence, if you are given the first three elements of the sequence and the number N.
3. I have included the Constraints within the programme. This problem is a submitted in a system and there is a time limit. I hit Memory Limit exceeded on last 2 cases.

Please help.

```
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        BigInteger c = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var fibonacciNumbers = new List<BigInteger> { a, b, c };
        BigInteger N = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    
        if ((a < -2000000000) || (b < -2000000000) || (c < -2000000000) || (a > 2000000000) || (b > 2000000000) || (c > 2000000000) || (N > 15000) || (N < 1))
        {
            throw new Exception("Argument out of range");
        }

        while (fibonacciNumbers.Count <= N)
        {
            var previous = fibonacciNumbers[fibonacciNumbers.Count - 1];
            var previous2 = fibonacciNumbers[fibonacciNumbers.Count - 2];
            var previous3 = fibonacciNumbers[fibonacciNumbers.Count - 3];
            fibonacciNumbers.Add(previous + previous2 + previous3);
        }

        Console.WriteLine((fibonacciNumbers[(int)N - 1]));
```

Comment: Yeah, of course you hit a memory limit if you have a list with that many elements in it. Those elements have to occupy some RAM, don't they? That leads me to the question: For what reason do you have that list? What purpose does it have? You can realize your algorithm without that list (or with a rather tiny list). Think a little bit about it...

Comment: I wanted to practice Lists that's why I overcomplicated it. I realized if I just use the 3 variables I need instead of populating them somewhere, I will save a lot of memory when working with a lot of numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't store all previous sequence values because you only need to store last 3 numbers to calculate next one.

```
BigInteger prevPrev = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
BigInteger prev = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
BigInteger current = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

BigInteger N = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 3; i < N; i++)
{
    // calculate next number
    var next = prevPrev + prev + current;

    // shift all numbers
    prevPrev = prev;
    prev = current;
    current = next;
}

return current;
```

Answer (score 2):

IF we assume that you need to store previous Fibonacci results in the list (if there is any purpose)?

With default configuration the maximum size of a CLR Object is 2GB even on 64bit.

you are storing fibonacci results in `List` which occupies memory. you are getting `OutOfMemoryException` When you hit 2GB

You need to surpass 2GB limit. For this you need to add `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` into `app.config`

```
<runtime>
  <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

---

On the other hand if you don't need all the previous values of fibonacci sequence, then

```
    BigInteger f2 = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    BigInteger f1 = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    BigInteger f = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    BigInteger N = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    
    if ((a < -2000000000) || (b < -2000000000) || (c < -2000000000) || (a > 2000000000) || (b > 2000000000) || (c > 2000000000) || (N > 15000) || (N < 1))
    {
        throw new Exception("Argument out of range");
    }

    while (fibonacciNumbers.Count <= N)
    {
        var fn = f2 + f1 + f;

        f2 = f1;
        f1 = f;
        f = fn;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things in your code that needs attention:

- Why would you store all preceding numbers into an array. As @Vadim Martynov already mentioned, you'll only need the previous three numbers (which isn't Fibonacci).
- You use a `BigInteger` to store the count. It probably should fit a 32-bit signed integer, because it would already be over 2 billion iterations. With `BigInteger` structures this will already take up too much memory. At the end of your current program, you already cast back to `int`, so there is no for using `BigInteger` here.

If you do want to store all items in a list (don't ask me why), then please do pre-allocate the list to the correct number (you know it in advance) and use an array, so you get a much more efficient storage that doesn't need to re-allocate and copy.

```
    var a = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var b = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var c = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if ((a < -2000000000) || (b < -2000000000) || (c < -2000000000) || (a > 2000000000) || (b > 2000000000) || (c > 2000000000) || (N > 15000) || (N < 1))
        throw new Exception("Argument out of range");

    var fibonacciNumbers = new BigInteger[N];
    fibonacciNumbers[0] = a;
    fibonacciNumbers[1] = b;
    fibonacciNumbers[2] = c;

    for (var i=3; i < N; ++i)
    {
        var previous = fibonacciNumbers[i - 1];
        var previous2 = fibonacciNumbers[i - 2];
        var previous3 = fibonacciNumbers[i - 3];
        fibonacciNumbers[i] = previous + previous2 + previous3;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(fibonacciNumbers[N - 1]);
```

But it's better not to store these items in an array/list anyway. I just wanted to comment on the other issues, but please use the answer of @Vadim Martynov.